# How do I launch an offline ClickOnce application with arguments from VB6?

Tags: vb6, clickonce

I know that you can pass command line parameters to offline ClickOnce applications ([see here for that](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-offline-clickonce-application/)).

In that example, it's launching it from .NET.  How would I launch it from VB6?

I tried using `ChDir` to change the directory to that folder, than then using `Shell` to execute it as a command line, but it's not working.  The error is "Invalid procedure call or argument".  Here's the command line I'm executing:

```
"C:\Users\{my user name}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\{my company name}\{my app name}.appref-ms"
```

This is where my offline application is.  I don't think the `Shell` command actually works for this type of file.

Comment: The VB6 Shell() function is a thin wrapper on CreateProcess(), so it runs programs and doesn't open documents.  You might try ShellExecute() with an "open" verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have more luck using the `ShellExecute` API. Here is a [link](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/codelib/shell/shellex.htm) to an example. In my experience this is more reliable than `Shell` and has more options to use.